# How to construct DStream from continued RDDs?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, pyspark

I`m reading data from ElasticSearch to Spark every 5min. So there will be a RDD every 5 minutes.

I hope to construct a DStream based on these RDDs, so that I can get report for data within last 1 day, last 1 hour , last 5 minutes and so on.

To construct the DStream, I was thinking about create my own receiver, but the official documents of spark only give information using scala or java to do so. And I use python.

So do you know any way to do it? I know we can. After all the DStream is a series of RDDs, of course we should be about create DStream from continued RDDs. I just do not know how. Please give some advice

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own receiver would be one way as you mentioned but seems like a lot of overhead. What you can do is to use a `QueueReceiver` which creates `QueueInputDStream` like in [this example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/QueueStream.scala). It's Scala but you should also be able to do a similar thing in Python:

```
val rddQueue = new Queue[RDD[Map[String, Any]]]()
val inputStream = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue)
```

Afterwards you simply query your ES instance every `X sec/min/h/day/whatever` and you put the results into that queue.

With Python I guess it would be something like this:

```
rddQueue = []
rddQueue += es_rdd() // method that returns an RDD from ES
inputStream = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue)

// some kind of loop that adds to rddQueue new RDDS
```

Apparently you need to have something in the queue before you use it inside `queueStream` (or at least I'm getting exceptions in `pyspark` if it's empty).

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz Dymczyk. The queueStream will not work because after you create the DStream. Any new rdd added into the queue will not count

Comment: @KramerLi ah you are right, I wonder if there is some way to change that behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use receivers. You can directly override the InputDStream class to implement your elasticsearch data pulling logic. It's a better approach to not rely on receivers when your data already benefits from a replicated and replayable storage.

See : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream

Though, I'm not sure you can easily create InputDStream classes directly from python.